# Need div to be populated with images from the bottom up

Tags: html

I'm trying to render a div with a set of small icon images laid out horizontally at the *bottom* of the div.

When the width of the total line of images is less than that of the containing div there isn't a problem.  I'm using code like this:

```
<div class="main-div" style="position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 600px">
Text text text ...
  <div class="icon-tray">
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS for "icon-tray" as follows:

```
div.icon-tray {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The "main-div" container is positioned with a fixed width and height; there's lots of space between the text at the top and the icons at the bottom.

The CSS above puts the "icon-tray" div of images all in a line at the bottom of the main div, which is just what I want.

However I've got a problem when the number of icons won't all fit on just one line.  When that happens the rendered main div looks like this:

```
--------------
|text text text ...
|
|
|
|X X X X X X X
|X X
--------------
```

The "icon-tray" div lays out the images line by line starting from the TOP; whereas I would like the icons to be seen as 'filling up' the main div from the bottom upwards, like this:

```
-------------
|text text text ...
|
|
|
|X X
|X X X X X X X
--------------
```

I don't have a clue as to how I can go about this.  How can I get the icons to be laid out from the bottom up?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Out of curiosity try adding `direction:rtl;` to the div.icon-try CSS definition.  This controls text direction but maybe it might work for what you are doing.

Comment: Hi cfeduke!  Thanks for your rapid response!  Adding "direction: rtl;" to the CSS changed the order of the icons in each line - rather than A B C D they were displayed as D C B A - but they were still laid out from the top down, with the bottom line only half-full.

Comment: Is the maximum number of icons known?  I guess more importantly would they ever require more blank lines to be inserted above them thus displacing the bottom line of icons?

Comment: Yes, the number of icons is known at the time of display, so I can certainly get this working in some way; it would have been nice if there was some CSS trick I didn't know about that did all the work for me!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this all with CSS - though you have to use some of the more non-standard properties. Since you have standardized to Firefox 3 though it shouldn't be a problem.

First you flip each image vertically, and then you flip the entire div vertically.

Also, I removed your `bottom: 0px;` style for `div.icon-tray`. There is no need for that with this method.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         div.icon-tray {
            position: absolute;
            -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
            transform: scaleY(-1);
            filter: FlipV;
            -ms-filter: "FlipV";
         }
         img {
            -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
            transform: scaleY(-1);
            filter: FlipV;
            -ms-filter: "FlipV";
         }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-div" style= "position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 600px">
      Text text text ...
      <div class="icon-tray">
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
        <img src="testing.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, if the order of the icons/images is important to you, you could try using the `direction: rtl;` method that @cfeduke mentioned in conjunction with this method.

Comment: That's brilliant Jeremy (I'll agree with your user name!), just what I'd hoped would be possible, some way for CSS to do it.  I didn't know about the transformation property, that's a great use for it.  I found that I did need the 'bottom: 0px' property, otherwise the icon-tray was just below the text, at the top of the main-div, and not at the bottom.  After adding that it all looks perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little obscure what you're trying to do.

Is this something you will want to be dynamic? If so, you should use some php to get number of images going to be displayed, divide by how many per row, then take the remainder and spit it out first.. somelike like that anyway.

If it's not going to be dynamic and just straight up html, would be easier to just abs position each image (considering your container div has a set width and height anyway?)

Comment: I'm developing a PHP/javascript program to replace a legacy application written in an older language.  It would be nice to be able to duplicate the appearance of the old application.  Plus there is a certain cosmetic elegance to what I'd like; put it the other way, the gap at the very bottom looks a little 'ugly' to me.  The icons may be of different size, and it would be a pain to have to handle them on the PHP server as well as the browser.  Ideally it would be nice if CSS would do all the work, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to resort to Javascript for this. I can't imagine any way to do it with CSS right now.

Here's what you could do with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var total = $('.icon-tray > img').size(),
        maxperrow = 7,  //edit this to the max. imgs per row
        breakafter = total-parseInt(total/maxperrow)*maxperrow;

        $('.icon-tray:nth-child('+breakafter+')').css({'clear':'left'});
});
```

The above is assuming you have your images set to float left.

edit: if you can do it server-side, even better. You can do the same math with PHP (for example) and don't have to rely on Javascript.

Comment: If I have to resort to javascript then that's fine; I know I'm not an expert in CSS and so was wondering if CSS could do all the work for me.  That said ... I like what you've presented here, very neat.  I would have probably laboriously positioned every single icon, maybe; your idea here of clearing the float on that top line to force a break strikes me as very elegant.  (I also didn't know about jQuery's 'nth-child').  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS3 (Chrome, IE9, Firefox4 this spring) then you can use:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/

I'd recommend reading:

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Browsers which don't support CSS3 will still get the top to bottom experience however.  You'll have to ask yourself if the time investment in using jQuery to position each icon based on width is worth the trouble to support older browsers.

Comment: We've standardised on Firefox 3, but it's good to know there are other layout managers to look forward to.  :-)  Thanks for the advice!